# How to hide time elapsed shown in zsh after every command

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

The time elasped is showing for all the themes, i am unable to turn it off. Additionally, there is a bug, it shows empty spaces sometimes and after few commands it comes back on.

[Screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSM63.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer probably lies in your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: there is no specific entry for the timer, rather i need an entry to disable the counter.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the answer *was* in my `~/.zshrc`. I have `REPORTTIME` set.

From [Ubuntu manpage for zshparam](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/zshparam.1.html):

> If nonnegative, commands whose combined user and system execution  times  (measured
> in  seconds)  are  greater than this value have timing statistics printed for them.
> Output is suppressed for  commands  executed  within  the  line  editor,  including
> completion;  commands  explicitly  marked  with  the  time  keyword still cause the
> summary to be printed in this case.